# Pin Generator - By Date Calculated - No Interaction - C#

Tags: c#, date, console.writeline

I hoped that I could get pointed in the right direction logic wise.

**Background Info**

A daily pin for an application is generated using a set of calculations based off month, day, year on a schedule that is known 5 months out. This schedule manipulates which parts of the date (month, day, year) are included in the calculation as well as how it's calculated (addition, subtraction, multiplication).

Instead of opening up my calculator to calculate this pin, referring to documentation, then calculating from that documentation, I would like to make a program that would do it for me and who knows even my co-workers if they keep feeding me.

My Experience with C# or other programming: a "Hello World" experience level.

**Summary of Research**

*Found answers to:
How to make a form in C#
How to transfer info from one textbox to the other in C#
How to Close an application
How to get the current date.
How to only get the date and not the time to show up in a textbox.
How to Transfer info from one textbox to another.

*Haven't found what I'm looking for:
How to parse a date from a textbox in another textbox.
How to calculate the parsed information on a rotating table.
How to parse a date using date time so that it can be calculated in another text box.

**My Goal**
Make the app not require user interaction so my co-workers I share with don't get mad when they don't input in the correct method.

Adjust the app every 5 months with the needed calculations (in which I'll figure out if I can push out an update automatically instead of installing it every 5 months).

Find that tidbit of logic I'm missing so that I can build on it from there and improve this app.

The Code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

 namespace Pin_Generator
{
public partial class Home : Form
{
    public Home()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        TodayDateTextBox.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
        TodayPasswordTextBox.Text = TodayDateTextBox.Text;

    }

    private void Home_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void CloseButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
        Application.Exit();

    }


    // private void TodayPasswordTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
   // {
   //     int MM;
   //     int dd;
   //     int yyyy;
```

When Debug the screen shows:

Todays Date: 5/19/2015

Todays Pin: 5/19/2015

The screen should show something like:
Todays Date: 5/19/2015
Todays Pin: 33289306093

I understand I still have a long way to go but I am seeing a lot of resources on how to calculate but not so much on how to calculate what I have as "Todays Date" to be transformed into a different number based off of the date. I've also just tried searching "How do I convert date into calculated string"

I think with the correct questions, I should be able to find the correct answers but so far my logic has differed and I haven't quite got the keywords down. Or it could be that I'm going about completely the wrong way, I understand that as well.

Thank you all in advance for your time and please let me know if you have any questions for me. I hope the screenshots help visualize where my mind is and hopefully I can get back on the right track with your help.

Comment: It's hard to advise on how to 'transform into a different number based off the date' without knowing how this calculation works.

Comment: What @CharlesMager said. I presume you know that once you have your `DateTime` object you can access Year, Month and Day properties to access the individual date parts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you create a method like the following to calculate your PIN.

```
    public string CalculatePIN()
    {
        DateTime today = DateTime.Now;
        int year = today.Year;
        int month = today.Month;
        int day = today.Day;

        string pin = // Do some calculation using the year month and day variables.

        return pin;
    }
```

you can modify your Home method to do the following...

```
    public Home()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        TodayDateTextBox.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
        TodayPasswordTextBox.Text = CalculatePIN();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Parsing the date from the text box is pretty easy

```
    DateTime dateInTextbox = DateTime.Parse(TodayDateTextBox.Text);
```

From that, I recommend you create a method that uses the `DateTime` object's properties to produce the password, then call it like this:

```
    TodayPasswordTextBox.Text = CalculatePassword(dateInTextbox);
```

From your question it sounds like your CalculatePassword() method will look something like this:

```
string CalculatePassword(DateTime target)
{
    const int startingPin = 123; // the number your rotation is based on
    DateTime current = DateTime.Parse("1/1/2015"); // the date your rotation starts from
    int currentPin = startingPin;
    while(current < target)
    {
        currentPin = CalculateNextPin(
            currentPin, current.Year, current.Month, current.Day);
        current = current.AddDays(1);
    }
    return currentPin.ToString();
}
```

Of course, you'll have to fill in the details for `CalculateNextPin()`'s implementation yourself.

Comment: The one thing I would be careful of is the `DateTime.Parse("1/1/2015")` if you don't have a starting date that does not have the same month and day value it could be interpreted differently depending on the culture currently active on the user's machine. For any dates that are not January 1st, Feburary 2nd, and so on I would switch it out to `new DateTime(2015,1,1)`

Comment: @ScottChamberlain: Agreed. I was originally going to do that, but with how new the OP is to C# I wanted to make it "read" more easily to someone with less .NET experience. I figured if he's parsing the current date out of a textbox in this format anyway, then it's just as likely to break there as in the CalculatePassword method.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a very late response, very busy past few weeks! Thank you all for the input. Wish I could mark more than one as an answer as every lit bit had helped me. I marked amcdermott as the answer but able to use info from StriplingWarrior for some other concepts. I was able to get this working beautifully with the following other tidbits of information I found on the logic.

Below is ultimately what I came up with to really get things rolling. Once I understood the logic of splitting up the DateTime and how to make strings into integers then back to strings, things have started to really come together.

```
   // Declares string values for each part of the DateTime format to be later calculated.
        string sYear = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy");
        string sMonth = DateTime.Now.ToString("MM");
        string sDay = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd");

        // Takes string values of the parsed DateTime values and converts them into integers.
        int iYear = Convert.ToInt32(sYear);
        int iMonth = Convert.ToInt32(sMonth);
        int iDay = Convert.ToInt32(sDay);


        // Takes the integer values and performs equations with them to get pin.
        int pass = iYear * iMonth * (iDay * iDay);

        // Takes calculation from above line to pass it back to a string.
        string today = pass.ToString();

        // Passes the above line into the PinTextBox for display to the operator.
        TodayPinTextBox.Text = today;
```

Answer (score 0):

This may like generate code for the transaction.

```
public string generateCode()
{
    DateTime today = DateTime.Now;
    int year = today.Year;
    int month = today.Month;
    int day = today.Day;
    int i = 0;
    do
    {
        i += 1;
        string code = "PUL" + Convert.ToString(year) + Convert.ToString(month) + Convert.ToString(day) + Convert.ToString(i);
        //you can change the format code as you want
        return code;
    } while (today == dtpTrans.Value);
}
```